# Is changing css stylesheet link in <head> html page trigger a new React render?

Tags: reactjs

1. I choose to switch theme in React within changing  css stylesheet link
2. I have a context ThemeProvider that trigger this  replacement (a stylesheet link with an other)
3. The ReactDOM.render is in  NOT in 
   ...
4. When I switch the css stylesheet there is a React render!
5. Is this a normal behavior?

Comment: is the head a child of some react component? If so, than yes it will.

Comment: No, it's not in some react component. So, according to your answer, I suppose that it's my context provider that re-render components.